# Make obsolete v delete classes

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

I have phased out a few classes from a project and removed all references to them.  Is it better practice to make them obsolete or delete them from the project?

I am a sole developer of this system.  I have spent some time Googling this and I have also looked at a few articles on MSDN.  However, I cannot find the answer to my specific question.

Comment: Well, I would say look at what Microsoft does with .NET, the methods are marked as obsolete but never removed as certain system may still require it. Plus if it's code that did important logic then you may want to keep it in case you need to ever refer back to it.

Comment: In `VisualStudio` objects marked as `Obsolete` will be raised in Warnings(Error list) with description which you set in `Obsolete` attribute

Comment: You can do both.  Mark them as Obsolete so that you do not write new code using them and be able to see how many times and where the old stuff is used.  Then at some point, rewrite that code to be able to remove the old ones.

Answer (score 1):

If nobody else is using your system it is redundant to keep this classes/methods.
Deprecating classes/methods is usefull if you got some clients of your code and you do not want to make their code crash. You are deprecating classes/methods then to indicate that new users should use something else.

Comment: Thanks +1.  That is what I thought.  Depreciate as a communication mechanism for other developers.  Do you know of any classes that were deleted rather than depreciated from the .NET framework?